# Get nodes between two paths using ltree in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, ltree

I'm using PostgreSQL with [ltree](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ltree.html) extension.

Consider I have the following structure in my database:

[image: nodes graph]

Given **C** node (path: `A.C`) as a start node and **I** node (path: `A.C.F.G.I`) as an end node I want to select all nodes between them including the boundaries. So, the result should include: **C**, **F**, **G**, **I**, but not the other nodes.

Is there a combination of built-in `ltree` functions I could use to write up a query?

Comment: I am trying to do the same thing. Did you find an answer?